# Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class EditText

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I am getting tired fixing this problem. the app does not execute it always show me this error

> Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class EditText.

I don't understand how to fix this problem

I have done changes in the `layout_width` and in `layout_height` but it did not fixed the issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Popup_AddItemFlipper"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Popup__ItemList"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <EditText android:id="@+id/txt_Popup_Search"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:hint="@string/apd_SearchButtonHint"
            android:background="#3B444B"/>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_Itemlist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:divider="#C4C3D0"
            android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
            android:scrollbars="none"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Popup__ItemDetails"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="30dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text=""
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/apd_ItemCodeLabel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_Popup_Itemcode"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#0B70B8"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:text="@string/apd_ItemNameLabel"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_Popup_ItemName"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#0B70B8"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text=""
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text=""
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <!--<EditText android:id="@+id/txt_Popup_ItemUnitPrice"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#3B444B"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;Unit Price"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:background="@drawable/clientid_layout_txtbg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:enabled="false"/>

        <EditText android:id="@+id/txt_apd_ItemQty"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#3B444B"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:hint="Quantity"
            android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_sync"
            android:background="@drawable/clientid_layout_txtbg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"/>-->


        <Button android:text="@string/apd_ItemWhs"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#3B444B"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/btn_apd_ItemWhs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <Button android:text="@string/apd_ItemTaxCode"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#3B444B"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/btn_apd_ItemTaxCode"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#3B444B"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/btn_apd_ItemRate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <Button android:text="@string/apd_ItemTotal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#3B444B"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:id="@+id/btn_apd_ItemTotal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"/>

        <Button android:text="@string/apd_ItemUpdate"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:background="#0B70B8"
            android:id="@+id/btn_apd_ItemUpdate"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

Binary XML file line #13: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class EditText

Comment: upload full error log also

Comment: is this @drawable/ic_search png or xml?

Comment: It's probably the drawable. Remove it and run again just to check.

Comment: `fill_parent` feels like 2010 again

Comment: I was about saying this too.

Comment: show full exception stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

I think you should Invalidate Caches and restart

To do that

Go to **File** -> **Invalidate Caches/Restart** -> **Invalidate**

I hope this helps!!